# Android logging: filter from the application itself

Tags: android, testing, junit, robolectric

Is there a way to programmatically configure an Android application to filter the log messages sent to logcat?  I do understand, that logcat can be configured to filter out stuff, but I want to do the same inside the Android application.

**Use case** - I am actually using **robolectric** for my test cases, that I can run directly on my host machine and not on an emulator.  This is actually extremely convenient for non-GUI stuff.  Some of my code emits Android logs.  I cannot attach logcat to see the output of that.  I can redirect logs to regular stdout.  But at this point I don't have filtering, so it's either grep or similar or sieving through thousands of lines of irrelevant stuff.

Comment: Create a proxy class to handle all log prints, and filter there?

Comment: Sure, I can do things like that.  Robolectric exposes a class called ShadowLog - one can reassign the stream there to private implementation with whatever filtering is desired.  I was wondering if something like that is available already one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I did:

```
    public class CustomPrintStream extends PrintStream {

    private String regexFilter;
private Pattern pattern;

public IonPrintStream(@NonNull File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    super(file);
}

public String getRegexFilter() {
    return regexFilter;
}

public void setRegexFilter(String regexFilter) {
    this.regexFilter = regexFilter;
    if (regexFilter != null && !regexFilter.isEmpty()) {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(regexFilter);
    } else {
        pattern = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void println(String x) {

    if (x != null && pattern != null && !pattern.matcher(x).find()) {
        return;
    }

    System.out.println(x);
}
}
```

Usage on Robolectric (you can do it on your @Before method):

```
        File file = new File("log.txt");
        if (!file.exists() && !file.createNewFile()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Log file could not be created");
        }

        CustomPrintStream printStream = new CustomPrintStream(file);
        printStream.setRegexFilter("[your regex here]");
        ShadowLog.stream = printStream;
```

In your case, as you don't want to show some logs, you could filter something like this:

```
        //I don't want to log CursorWindowStats and SQLiteCursor tags:
        printStream.setRegexFilter("^((?!CursorWindowStats|SQLiteCursor).)*$");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin:

```kotlin
class FilterLogStream(stream: OutputStream, private val pattern: Pattern) : PrintStream(stream) {
    override fun println(x: String) {
        if (!pattern.matcher(x).find()) return
        super.println(x)
    }
}

fun PrintStream.filter(regex: String): PrintStream = FilterLogStream(this, Pattern.compile(regex))
```

usage:

```kotlin
ShadowLog.stream = System.out.filter("^(?!W/ShadowLegacyPath).*$")
```